# Getting Domain Name from URl

Tags: c#, uri

I need to extract the exact domain name from any Url.

For example,

- URL1: "http://www.something.subdomain.com" -- > it should output to --> http://something.subdomain.com
- URL2: "http://www.something.com" -- > it should output to --> http://something.com
- URL3: "http://www.1234.seequip.com" -- > it should output to --> http://1234.seequip.com
- URL4: "https://secure.subdomain.com" -- > it should output to --> https://secure.subdomain.com

This is what i had tried so far this is not returning the exact results i am expecting can any one help me here

```
   public static string GetDomainName(string domainURL) {
            string domain = new Uri(domainURL).DnsSafeHost.ToLower();
            var tokens = domain.Split('.');
            if (tokens.Length > 2)
            {
                //Add only second level exceptions to the < 3 rule here
                string[] exceptions = { "info", "firm", "name", "com", "biz", "gen", "ltd", "web", "net", "pro", "org" };
                var validTokens = 2 + ((tokens[tokens.Length - 2].Length < 3 || exceptions.Contains(tokens[tokens.Length - 2])) ? 1 : 0);
                domain = string.Join(".", tokens, tokens.Length - validTokens, validTokens);
            }
            return domain;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the URI class found in  System namespace

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.something.com/");
```

It has properties such as **host** which should get you want you need...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
public string GetDomainName(string domainURL)
{
    string domain = new Uri(domainURL).DnsSafeHost.ToLower();
    domain = domainURL.Split(':')[0] + "://" + domain;
    return domain;
}
```

I think you should split and get the protocol from starting of the string and append it to domain. If you pass any URL without protocol like `http://` the code `new Uri()` method will throw error.

So, I think the code `domainURL.Split(':')[0] + "://" + domain;` will work for you.

Please test it with your proposed inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to extract the parts using the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class and then put the pieces you want back together.

However, it seemed as though you specifically wanted the "**www.**" piece removed, so I threw in a string replace for that.

```
Uri MyUri = new Uri(domainURL);

string Result = MyUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme);

Result += MyUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped).Replace("www.", string.Empty);

return Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.something.subdomain.com");
        string host = myUri.Host;
```

host is what you are looking for.